# Rails error uninitialized constant User::Friendship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, uninitialized-constant

I'm working on a project that has a typical friendship model. User Class needs to have a self-referencing relationship so each user can befriend multiple friends and can be befriended by multiple users... In short i need the exact same thing described in this tutorial:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast

But after following the whole video to the letter i get this error

```
uninitialized constant User::Friendship
```

This is what my User model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
end
```

Friendship model:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name => "User"
end
```

And the create method of the friendships_controller

```
def create
    current_user = User.find(session[:user])
    # BELOW LINE HAS THE ERROR
    current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @friendship.save
        format.html { redirect_to @friendship, notice: 'User Added To your team.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @friendship }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @friendship.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I don't know if it matters or not but I'm not using any user management plugin like Ryan in the video (I think he's using OAuth or something) ... 
Plus I did not generate the Friendship controller through nifty_scaffold as he does in the tutorial
here's the command I used to generate the scaffold

```
rails generate scaffold Friendship user_id:integer friend_id:integer create destroy
```

plus here's my ruby and rails versions if it helps...

```
Rails version 4.1.7
Ruby version 2.0.0p481
```

I've been trying to debug my code, searching the internet to figure out whats wrong but noting seems to work. Any thoughts on what might be the problem?

Comment: on your User model, what happens when you add the following to:`has_many :friendships, :class_name => "Friendship"`

Comment: You might just need a :source => :friend on this `has_many :friends, :through => :friendships`

Comment: (Did you mean 'belongs_to :friend, class_name => "User"', because I would expect 'belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"' with the extra colon at the beginning of class_name.)